# More optimized TreeMap::computeIfAbsent method

Tags: java, treemap

I'm using a TreeMap to store a mapping from longs to a TreeSet of longs. When I'm inserting new elements I use the following code:

```
treeMap.computeIfAbsent(key,k -> new TreeSet<>()).add(val);
```

However, looking at the source of this function it fetches the element, computes the new value if the key didn't exist and puts the computed value in the map. This means that it finds the position of the key two times. The map I'm using is pretty big and performance critical. Unfortunately I cannot extend the class as all the necessary variables are private.

Is there an implementation of TreeMap that has a more efficient computeIfAbsent?

Comment: I would suggest that before you try to optimize this, you should measure the impact of this function. Use a profiler as the one in JVisualVM and determine whether your function that uses the computeIfAbsent uses a considerable amount of time. I would guess that looking for the key is very fast if the hash function of your key Type is not too complicated

Comment: @JFMeier Upon further inspection it is apparent that the function has minimal affect on the performance of the algorithm. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If the performance is really needed, check the [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) library. It contains `Long2ObjectAvlTreeMap` and `Long2ObjectRBTreeMap`. Choose whichever suits your use-case best.